# No puedo ordenar en PDO y PHP

Tags: php, html, pdo

Buen día comunidad, estoy desarrollando una aplicación en PDO y php anexo el Código:

```
public function getList()
{
    try {
        // búsqueda por palabra clave
        $sqlQuery = '';

        if (!empty($this->_searchVal)) {
            $sqlQuery .= 'WHERE (ID LIKE "%'.$this->_searchVal.'%" ';
            $sqlQuery .= ' OR nombre LIKE "%'.$this->_searchVal.'%" ';
            $sqlQuery .= ' OR telefono LIKE "%'.$this->_searchVal.'%" ';
            $sqlQuery .= ' OR email LIKE "%'.$this->_searchVal.'%" ';
            $sqlQuery .= ' OR fecha_nac LIKE "%'.$this->_searchVal.'%" ';
            $sqlQuery .= ' OR edad LIKE "%'.$this->_searchVal.'%" ';
            $sqlQuery .= ' OR rama LIKE "%'.$this->_searchVal.'%" )';
        }

        // clasificación
        if (!empty($this->_orderBy)) {
            $sqlQuery .= 'ORDER BY '.$this->_orderBy['0']['column'].' '.$this->_orderBy['0']['dir'].' ';
        } else {
            $sqlQuery .= 'ORDER BY ID DESC ';
        }

        // Paginacion
        if ($this->_length != -1) {
            $sqlQuery .= ' LIMIT :limit,:offset';
        }

        $sql = "SELECT ID, nombre,telefono, email, fecha_nac, rama, edad FROM empleados".$sqlQuery;
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':limit', (int) $this->_start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':offset', (int) $this->_length, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $result;
    } catch (Exception $err) {
        die("Error!: ".$err);
    }
}
```

Estoy tratando de ordenar, pero me sale ese error ya trate de cambiar de campo y sale igual.
Espero alguna sugerencia :( ya le di mil vueltas y no veo el error

Error!: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,10'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En estos casos, ayuda bastante **pintar la consulta SQL completa**, y mirar ahí donde el mensaje de error nos está diciendo. En tu caso, el problema creo que es que **no dejas espacio** antes de concatenar $sqlQuery (poner un espacio justo después de "empleados");

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, nombre,telefono, email, fecha_nac, rama, edad FROM empleados ".$sqlQuery;
```

Porque, analizando el código, la variable $sqlQuery tampoco empieza por un espacio, con lo que estás juntando "empleados" con el principio $sqlQuery, ya sera "WHERE" o "ORDER".

Una tontería fácil de ver haciendo lo que te he dicho de depurar pintando la consulta completa.

Comment: Gracias amigo, si funcionó